# Field interactions and virtual photons

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, virtual-particles

How can one describe the interaction of the fields of two electrons along the area of contact of their fields?

In the approach and subsequent repulsion of two electrons, the only concept I know of is the asymmetric passage of a virtual photon from one to the other electron.

[image]

There is another sketch that I am more comfortable with, which shows the virtual photon also time dependent, in which case the beginning and end of the virtual photon are offset in height. But this shows that there is an asymmetric process for two identical particles, which makes me think of an oversimplification of the diagram.

However, if I look at a larger context, there is an electric field around each of the charges. The field lines used to represent them - in reality a surface - show the fields diverging from each other. Are virtual photons exchanged along the neutral surface and the Feynman diagram is far too simplistic? However, whenever I look at the Feynman diagram, doubts remain about an oversimplification.

How can one describe the interaction of the fields of two electrons along the area of contact of their fields?

Comment: Feynman diagrams were not invented to represent what happens, but to represent transition amplitudes between two asymptotic states. Yes, this is an oversimplification because virtual particles are mathematical artifacts from the perturbative expansion of the $S$ matrix we use.

Comment: There is no “area of contact of their fields”. Draw the fields of each electron separately. Each one extends throughout all space. At every point, the total field is the vector sum of the two fields. The diagram of the field lines of the total field has misled you into thinking that the individual fields don’t overlap.